# IF else && statement in React JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

Hey guys I am having trouble understanding how to create an IF else & statement in React.  All documentation, videos and questions that I find online only show the method of doing one of them, either an IF else or an &&

Basically the IF statement I am trying to create within the JSX looks like this.

```
If(data.AP == "1" && data.MP == "1")
{
set.Text("Both")
}
else if(data.AP == "0" && data.MP == "1")
{
set.Text("Manager")
}
else if(Data.AP == "1" && data.MP == "0")
{
set.Text("Payroll")
}
else{
setText("Not Approved)
}
```

A fairly simple IF statement in Java but I can't seem to find a way to translate this into JSX.  So far this is the furthest I have got and it keeps giving me errors whenever I chop and change it depending on the documentation I am reading.  I know how to use ?? Ternary operators and && operators but using them together doesnt seem to work for me.

```
 return (

   {
  data.MP == "1" && data.AP == "1" && (
     <td colSpan="1">{"Both"}</td> ) : null
  }

)
```

Comment: Use `switch` statement.

Comment: @MileMijatović - The above isn't a good match for `switch`. You **could** do it (`switch (true) { case data.MP == "1" && data.AP == "1": ...`) but it's just as clunky -- or clunkier -- than the `if`/`else if`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can concatenate as many if else as required:

```
data.AP == "1" && data.MP == "1" ? FIRST THEN HERE :
  data.AP == "0" && data.MP == "1" ? SECOND THEN HERE :
    data.AP == "1" && data.MP == "0" ? THIRD THEN HERE :
      ELSE THEN HERE
```

Replace the text with the desired expression

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I suggest you do it:

```
let text;
if (data.AP == "1" && data.MP == "1") {
    text = "Both";
} else if (data.AP == "0" && data.MP == "1") {
    text = "Manager";
} else if (data.AP == "1" && data.MP == "0") {
    text = "Payroll";
} else {
    text = "Not Approved";
}
// ...then when you want to display it:
{text}
```

...because that's easy to read and debug.

But if you really want to embed it in `{...}`, you can use a nested series of conditional operators:

```
{
    data.AP == "1" && data.MP == "1"
    ? "Both"
    : data.AP == "0" && data.MP == "1"
        ? "Manager"
        : data.AP == "1" && data.MP == "0"
            ? "Payroll"
            : "Not Approved"
}
```

Although you can make it *fairly* readable (though not very debuggable):

```
{
      data.AP == "1" && data.MP == "1" ? "Both"
    : data.AP == "0" && data.MP == "1" ? "Manager"
    : data.AP == "1" && data.MP == "0" ? "Payroll"
    :                                    "Not Approved"
}
```

If you use an automatic code formatter, it may well reformat it though.